# ActiveSync "foldersync" command response

Tags: ios, activesync

I am developing EAS Client and I am stuck with the FolderSync command. I am getting hex data as response which I am unable to parse.

I searched over forums and found that there is xml/wbxml response from the server but I don't know how to decode the response.

Below is the hex data.

> 03016a00 0007564c 03310001 52033100 014e5703 31310001 4f480331
>   00014903 30000147 0343616c 656e6461 7200014a 03380001 014f4803
>   32000149 03300001 4703436f 6e746163 74730001 4a033900 01014f48
>   03330001 49033000 01470344 656c6574 65642049 74656d73 00014a03
>   34000101 4f480334 00014903 30000147 03447261 66747300 014a0333
>   0001014f 48033500 01490330 00014703 496e626f 7800014a 03320001
>   014f4803 36000149 03300001 47034a6f 75726e61 6c00014a 03313100
>   01014f48 03370001 49033000 0147034a 756e6b20 456d6169 6c00014a
>   03313200 01014f48 03380001 49033000 0147034e 6f746573 00014a03
>   31300001 014f4803 39000149 03300001 47034f75 74626f78 00014a03
>   36000101 4f480331 30000149 03300001 47035365 6e742049 74656d73
>   00014a03 35000101 4f480331 31000149 03300001 47035461 736b7300
>   014a0337 00010101 01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by using third party c++ library to covert data from/to wbxml.

Answer (score 0):

libwbxml2 can be used for parsing the binary WBXML data. Code with the latest tags can be found here:
https://github.com/nemomobile-packages/libwbxml2.git

Here is how binary data can be converted to XML format:

```
WB_ULONG xmlLength = 0;
WB_UTINY *xml = NULL;
WBXMLGenXMLParams params = {WBXML_GEN_XML_INDENT, WBXML_LANG_AIRSYNC, 2, TRUE};
wbxml_conv_wbxml2xml_withlen(wbxmlBuffer, wbxmlBufferLength, &xml, &xmlLength, &params);
printf("%s", xml);
```